# Using Regexp for search XML

Tags: xml, regex, delphi

How can I search an xml file by Regex and get specific attribute value in Delphi?

For example in this xml:

```
<?xml version=”1.0” encoding=”UTF-8” ?> 
<School>
    <Class>
        <StudentID> 1 </StudentID> 
        <StudentName> Joe </StudentName> 
        <StudentFamily> Brown </StudentFamily> 
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <StudentID> 2 </StudentID> 
        <StudentName> Michel </StudentName> 
        <StudentFamily> Adams </StudentFamily> 
    </Class>
    <Class>
        <StudentID> 3 </StudentID> 
        <StudentName> Joel </StudentName> 
        <StudentFamily> Thompson </StudentFamily> 
    </Class>

</School>
```

That is, searching for “Joe*” (in StudentName attribute) the code should return “Brown” and “Thompson” (from StudentFamily attribute).

I can use FindNode function for xmlDocument in simple cases, but I have to use Regex.

Any idea is welcome.

Comment: Are there any language restrictions for the regex you're writing? Also, is there a reason you can't just use xpath for this?

Comment: I recommend to use Xpath. That will be more feasible.

Comment: This question has already been answered by bobince: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: FWIW, I did not cast a duplicate close vote. Mine was for "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Thanks David,in fact my question is about searching nodes by regex, and return related nodes in Delphi. I can do the search properly, but can not get related nodes in delphi.

Comment: Stop using regex for this task. It is the wrong tool.

Answer (score 0):

How about:
`(?:\<StudentName\> Joe.* \<\/StudentName\>[\s]*<StudentFamily>\s*)(\w*)`
Of course, you have to build the pattern and put "Joe*" as "Joe.*" in the right place

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
(?:<StudentName>\sjoe[^< ]*).*?\n.*?<StudentFamily>([^<]*)
```

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nA2tI7)**

**Explanation :** 
 [image]